# $_GET variable is being set to something despite there being no intentional input

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to set up a REST API and when the URL is say, for example, `api/family` it would return a JSON object with that info. However, when I do `api/` with nothing after the forward slash I am being told that `isset($_GET['url'])` is `true`. I have tried trimming the array as I initial thought it was some white space, but that wasn't the case either. In general the PHP code is:

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
   echo "WRONG";
}
```

While I don't think it is the case it possible that I set up the `htacess` incorrectly, but it is the only other thing I can think of that might have an effect the `$_GET` variable (even though it shouldn't).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule api/(.*)$ api/api.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help discovering why the `isset` is outputting true would be appreciated.

Comment: It's *always* set thanks to your rewrite rule. You need to check if it *contains a value*.

Comment: As mentioned, you could perform an `empty($_GET['url'])` check

Comment: @JohnConde Do you have any suggestions on improving it? I think I get why it is occurring that is, the url is becoming api/api.php?url=  in other words url is an "empty" value. Also, on a side note up until not too long ago I had it redirecting localhost/api/ to api/api.php so an improvement suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you simply check what's really inside the variable `$_GET['url']`? Ideally using a debugger or for example `var_dump($_GET['url'])`? You would find out that such `$_GET` array key is set to an empty string as @Cale W. Vernon explains in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better yet, **don't allow an empty value for your rewrite rule**. That will make it so it won't rewrite to your api URL unless there is an actual value there.

change your regex in the rewriterule pattern from

```
RewriteRule api/(.*)$ api/api.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

To this

```
RewriteRule api/(.+)/?$ api/api.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

You can still do `if(!empty($_GET['url']))` to ensure it's not but it never should be because apache wont rerwrite it unless there is a value there.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned via comments, you are basically setting `url` to an empty value through your `RewriteRule api/(.*)$ api/api.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` rule.

You may want to try checking the contents of `url` such as through `if(empty($_GET['url'])` or `empty($_GET['url'])`. Using `isset($_GET['url'])` will return `true` in this case because `url` is set, just not holding an actual definition.

---

@PanamaJack offers excellent advice in changing the `RewriteRule` itself which would act as a much longer term and larger scope solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check

```
if ($_GET['url']=='') {
    echo "WRONG";
}
```

or with isset too as

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    if ($_GET['url']=='') {
        echo "WRONG";
    }
}
```